# Can't Convert String to Bytes

Tags: python, arrays, string, byte

I'm trying to convert a string like this: "1234" to a byte array:
bytearray(b'\x12\x34') but the output from

```
line="1234"
print(bytearray.fromhex(line))
```

is bytearray(b'\x124') which is missing the 3

Any idea what is going on here? I have a long hex file that I am trying to read into a byte arrays

Comment: Its right there in the output. Did you check it? For instance, how long do you think the output should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `3` that you are missing is right there in: `bytearray(b'\x124')`. Can you see the `4` on the end. That is `\x34`. And there is your `3`.

Follow this example. It shows how converting from a string to `bytearray` and back recovers the information:

```py
for line in ("1212", "1234"):
    print(len(line), line)
    h = bytearray.fromhex(line)
    print(len(h), h)

    l = h.hex()
    print(len(l), l)
```

Output:

```
4 1212
2 bytearray(b'\x12\x12')
4 1212
4 1234
2 bytearray(b'\x124')
4 1234
```

Can you see how the lengths go from `4` to `2` and back to `4`?

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain a little more how the 4 on the end represents \x34?

Comment: So, what does `\x34` represent to you?

Comment: I just see (b'\x124') without the 3

Comment: What is actually there is '\x12' followed by '4'. It is bytearray which is trying to be 'helpful' and instead of printing '\x34' it converts it to an ASCII character and you get '4'.